# How to preserve line endings in Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby

I am running Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows. When I run the following snippet of code

```
text = File.read(path)
File.write(path, text)
```

I get the exact same file when the file has CR+LF line endings. When I run this on a file with LF line endings, it changes to CR+LF line endings.

How can I read from and write to a file using Ruby on Windows such that line endings are preserved, whether CR+LF or LF?

Answer (score 7):

Ruby, along with Perl and probably Python, are aware of the OS the code is running on, and will automatically set what the line-endings should be.

If you read, then write, a text file, those settings will kick in, and you'll see the file change like you are.

If you need to have the file be unchanged, add a `b` flag to an [`open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#method-c-open) statement, like:

```
File.open('path', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write(text)
end
```

For more information, see "[IO Open Mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)".

Comment: This preserves LF line endings, but now CR+LF line endings are converted to LF.