# Why is \r\n being converted to \n when a string is saved to a file?

Tags: ruby, regex, newline

The string is originating as a return value from:

```
> msg = imap.uid_fetch(uid, ["RFC822"])[0].attr["RFC822"]
```

In the console if I type msg, a long string is displayed with double quotes and \r\n separating each line:

```
> msg
"Delivered-To: email@test.com\r\nReceived: by xx.xx.xx.xx with SMTP id;\r\n"
```

If I match part of it with a regex, the return value has \r\n:

```
> msg[/Delivered-To:.*?\s+Received:/i]
=> "Delivered-To: email@test.com\r\nReceived:"
```

If I save the string to a file, read it back in and match it with the same regex, I get \n instead of \r\n:

```
> File.write('test.txt', msg)
> str = File.read('test.txt')
> str[/Delivered-To:.*?\s+Received:/i]
=> "Delivered-To: email@test.com\nReceived:"
```

Is \r\n being converted to \n when the string is saved to a file?
Is there a way to save the string to a file, read it back in without the line endings being modified?

Comment: may be its due to the operating system?
see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27323188/3286583

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered in [the IO.new documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode):

> The following modes must be used separately, and along with one or more of the modes seen above.

```
"b"  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.

"t"  Text file mode
```

In other words, Ruby, like many other languages, senses the OS it's on and will automatically translate line-ends between "\r\n" <-> "\n" when reading/writing a file in text mode. Use binary mode to avoid translation.

---

```
str = File.read('test.txt')
```

A better practice would be to read the file using `foreach`, which negates the need to even care about line-endings; You'll get each line separately. An alternate is to use `readlines`, however it uses [slurping which can be very costly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad) on large files.

Also, if you're processing mail files, I'd strongly recommend using something written to do so rather than write your own. The [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem is one such package that's pre-built and well tested.